# How to apply different set of colors to each item in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl and want each item to set its color theme based on data it contains. I have 2 resource dictionaries for 2 possible themes (Red and Blue) and a DataTemplate that defines how to apply those colors. How do I assign current resource dictionary for each row?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- 2 dictionaries with style colors -->
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="RedStyle">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="Red" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="Red" />
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="BlueStyle">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="Blue" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="Blue" />
            </ResourceDictionary>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="TextBrush" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*Update:* The DataTemplate and brush sets are much larger in my real project. What I'm trying to do is to avoid duplicating DataTemplate layout code while still being able to have 2 different color styles on it.

Comment: Are you wanting to assign the color based on some attribute of the data that is being templated?  The index?  Something else entirely?

Comment: Yes items contain an attribute that can be converted into style name

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your task, you can apply `DataTriggers` like shown in the following example:

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.TheAttribute}" Value="AttributeValue1">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="TextBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.TheAttribute}" Value="AttributeValue2">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="TextBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Style>
```

In this example, you do not need the `Styles` specified in your `ResourceDictionary`.

Alternatively, you can use `<Style.Triggers>` to set the `Style` per your `ResourceDictionary` rather than setting the values of individual properties.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Note : You cannot apply ResourceDictionary conditionally, using Triggers.

You have four options at your disposable.

1. Put your `DataTemplate` in single resource dictionary, or corresponding `DataTemplate`s in separate dictionaries.

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}">
           <TextBlock.Style>
               <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Name1">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                       </Trigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </TextBlock.Style>
       </TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>

   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

   Usage :

   ```
      <ItemsControl.Resources>            
               <ResourceDictionary Source="RedStyle.xaml"/>
      </ItemsControl.Resources>
   ```
2. Use `DataTemplateSelector` to apply some complicated logic and assign `DataTemplates` accordingly. There are good [tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_3) on net on this.
3. Use Blend Behaviors to do this using pure XAML.
4. Use `Loaded` event of the control present in `DataTemplate` to load Res Dictionary using code. Simplest approach !

   ```
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" Text="{Binding .}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
   ```

   Code :

   ```
       private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
           if (tb.Text == "Name123")
               tb.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("RedStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });
       }
   ```

Comment: I don't understand some parts. You are writing examples as if I have multiple DataTemplates. I have only 1 DataTemplate and 2 sets of brushes. I'm trying to avoid duplicating DataTemplate layout code because the one in my real project is rather large.

Comment: @Poma I am suggesting ways to do. Because what you are trying to do is not possible. Conditional Res Dictionary loading is not possible without code. See my last part carefully, or update your question more.

Answer (score 0):

There is an AlternationCount:

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

plus:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" TargetName="Grid" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF1F1F1" TargetName="Grid" />
    </Trigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```